# Grouping lines with a header using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex query that groups lines which start with a type of key as a header.

For example the key will be an line containing an 'A' followed by a number, I'm alternating bold lines to indicate a group. So the first 4 lines are one group, the next 2 a group etc. :

**dd A3**

**This line is arbitrary**

**This line is also arbitrary**

**1234 Arbitrary**

*A9*

*This line is arbitrary*

**ff A3 d**

*A5ff*

*Hi there*

*Hello*

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the text?  Extract, replace, something else?

Comment: Extract it, but using a tool.

Comment: Show us clean sample input, the output you want, and the tool/language you plan to use.

Comment: What is the tool?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with that worked: .`A[0-9].*\n((?!A[0-9]).|\n)`

Comment: Does it really work? Please show the code you are using it in.